# oAuth 2.0: How to Specify Scope in "Username and Password" Flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, pinterest

I need to get [Pinterest oAuth 2.0](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/authentication/) access token on the server side by username and password.

I use the following URL for that:

https://api.pinterest.com/v1/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=XXX&client_secret=XXX&username=XXX&password=XXX

It gives me the access token, but it doesn't seem to authorize any "scopes".
Is it possible to authorize some scopes (i.e. scope=read_public) without having to enter username & password in a popup?

I'd use a permanent refresh token for that, but Pinterest doesn't seem to provide it, only short-term access tokens.

Comment: There is a reason that method is undocumented. It will probably be ripped out in the near future. Sorry, man.

Comment: @ZackArgyle, so there's no way to get access token by username and password in v1?

Comment: @ZackArgyle, I need to be able to perform some offline actions on behalf of a user, what's the right way to handle that? Would that enough to get an access token and store it in db?

Comment: Yup, access token should be perfectly fine. They currently do not expire so you shouldn't have to worry about refreshing.